# Solve for Theta

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Solve for $\theta$, $y=xtan(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}a(\frac{x}{vcos(\theta)})^2$. I've tried to solve this using a calculator (didn't return any results), by taking the derivative/antiderivative of both sides, etc, but didn't manage to get anywhere. It is for a code on Stormworks; symbolically is best but any answer I will be grateful for. You can assume v and a are both constant (for the sake of integrals and derivatives). Thanks!

Comment: You can solve it completely symbolically by multiplying both sides by $\cos(\theta)$ and then use an identity to combine $y\cos(\theta)-x\sin(\theta)$; https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Simplifying_a_sin(x)_%2B_b_cos(x)

Comment: What happens to the $\frac{x^2}{v^2 cos(\theta)}$ on the right side?

Comment: @LachlanChu, is it $\frac{x^2}{v^2 cos(\theta)}$ or $\frac{x}{v cos(\theta)}$???

Comment: The cosine in the denominator should be cancelled out, unless you have a typo in your post.

Comment: That's my mistake; the question should have said $(\frac{x}{vcos(\theta)})^2$. Is this still solvable?

Comment: Standard usage is $x\tan(\theta) + \frac12a\left(\frac x{v\cos(\theta)}\right)$ or $x\tan\theta + \frac12a\left(\frac x{v\cos\theta}\right)$ rather than $x tan(\theta) + \frac12a(\frac x{v cos(\theta)})$.

Comment: Thanks, but how does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equation of a the trajectory of an object that is thrown at an initial horizontal velocity $v$, at an angle $\theta$ relative to the ground, and moves under the influence of the gravity field which generates an acceleretion $a$ in the direction downward (toward negative $y$)=free fall. $x$ is the horizonatl displacement and $y$ is the vertical displacement. It can be solved for $\theta$ by using the identity:
$1+\tan^2\theta=\frac1{\cos^2\theta}$, which makes it a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$:
$$
y= x\tan\theta+\frac{ax^2}{2v^2}(\tan^2\theta+1)
$$
or:
$$
\frac{ax^2}{2v^2}\tan^2\theta+x\tan\theta+\frac{ax^2}{2v^2}-y=0
$$
with the solutions:
$$
\tan\theta_{1,2}=\frac{v^2}{ax^2}\bigg[-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4\frac {ax^2}{2v^2}\big(\frac {ax^2}{2v^2}-y\big)}\bigg]
$$
The 2 solutions correspond to throwing above and below the horizon (in the latter the thrower should make the throw at some finite height above ground)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the meaning in physics.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, your equation is

$$y = x\ \text{tg}(\theta) + \frac{B}{\cos^2(\theta)}$$

For whatever $B$.

Note that you can rewrite it by multiplying by $\cos^2(\theta)$ (declaring the opportune conditions) as

$$y\cos^2(\theta) = x\ \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) + B$$

Now use

$$\cos^2(\theta) = \frac{1 + \cos(2\theta)}{2}$$
and
$$\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$$

to write it as

$$y\cos(2\theta) - x\sin(2\theta) = 2B - y$$

Now you can use $\cos(2\theta) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(2\theta)}$, call $\sin(2\theta) = t$:

$$y\sqrt{1 - t^2} = (2B - y) + xt$$

Square both members, isolate $t$ and solve for $t$. Then go back to $t = \sin(2\theta)$

Comment: Thank you—that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With $t:=\sec^2\theta$, the equation has the form

$$\pm x\sqrt{t-1}+\frac{ax^2}{2v^2}t=y.$$

By squaring, you get a quadratic equation in $t$,

$$x^2(t-1)=\left(y-\frac{ax^2}{2v^2}t\right)^2.$$